# Attachment in Laravel many-to-many relation

Tags: laravel, routes, controller, laravel-8

I'm trying to do my first attachment/ detachment. I'm using two tables, user, event, and its pivot, event_user. For this one, I needed to do a button to subscribe the user to an event, so my teacher told me to use an  and route it to the method subscribe. At this moment, the error that comes up is.

> Route [subscribe] not defined.

**Blade**

```
<a href="{{ route('subscribe', $event->event_id) }}" 
    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Subscribe</a>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/subscribe', [SubscribeController::class, 'index']);
```

**SubscribeController**

```
public function index($id)
{   
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->events->attach($id);

    return view('index');
}
```

I tried putting URL instead of the route in the , and it goes to /subscribe, but comes to an error that says -> Too few arguments to function 0 passed and exactly 1 expected.

I did a `dd()` in the component to see if the event id was the correct one, and it was. Also, apart from these errors, how can I route a method without changing the route? Can I do it using the indexController (because it's in the index where these events are located)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in order to reference the route by name, you need to give it the name `subscribe`.
Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#named-routes

Second, you want to add that `id` route parameter that you are trying to use in your controller.
Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#required-parameters

So your route should end up looking like this:

```
Route::get('/subscribe/{id}', [SubscribeController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('subscribe');
```

And then you'll want to call it like this:

```
<a href="{{ route('subscribe', ['id' => $event->event_id]) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in your blade view file you are trying to generate url using `route` helper like this

```
<a href="{{ route('subscribe', $event->event_id) }}" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Subscribe</a>`
```

The way you call the `route` helper we can supposed this

1. You have already define a route in your `web.php` file which is named `subscribe`
2. and that route have **paramater**

But in your `web.php` file you have this route

```
Route::get('/subscribe', [SubscribeController::class, 'index']);
```

1. This route doesn't have any name.
2. And it doesn't expect any parameter

To fix that you should only change the way you have define you route in the `web.php` file like this

```
Route::get('/subscribe/{id}', [SubscribeController::class, 'index'])
    ->name('subscribe');
```

With this route we define:

1. `id` as a required parameter
2. And the route is named **subscribe**